# React Router V4 - Page does not rerender on changed Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am building a small App to learn React with Meteor.
The user is asked to input a location, based on this location the user gets routed to a new page, where the location is displayed on the top of the page and some data from the database based on that location (not yet, this is my next step). 
I store the location in state on the component. Now it would be nice if the user could change the location. 
This is easy: just update state, e voilá. Or so I thought. The problem now is that the URL doesn't update, which looks dumb.
I then thought: "Okay, lets check on click if old location (in state) and new location (from input) are different, and if so set a redirect state"
In my render function if redirect is set I would just route the user to the same page again, but now the page won't reload. Any Ideas?

I know there are a thousand questions on react router v4 out there right now, because they just updated the version recently. I have been reading documentation for the last hours and just can't wrap my head around it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'
import LocationPicker from './LocationPicker'

export default class LocationDisplay extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.setLocation = this.setLocation.bind(this);
        this.state = {redirect: false};
    }

    setLocation(value) {
        this.setState({locationId: value});
        if (this.state.locationId != value) {
            this.setState({redirect : true})
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            locationId: this.props.match.params.locationId,
        });
    }

    render () {
        return (
            this.state.redirect 
            ? 
            <Redirect push to={{
                pathname: `/location/${this.state.locationId}`
            }}/> 
            :
            <div>
                <LocationPicker 
                    returnLocation={this.setLocation} 
                    locationId={this.state.locationId}
                />
                <h1>Please find below all recommendations for {this.state.locationId}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

And here my Routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import App from './App';
import LocationPicker from './LocationPicker';
import LocationDisplay from './LocationDisplay';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    render(
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Route exact path="/" component={LocationPicker}/>
                <Route path="/location/:locationId" component={LocationDisplay}/>
            </div>
        </Router>,
         document.getElementById('render-target')
    );
});
```

**Update:**

I tried using `<Link>` instead of `<Redirect>`, however this has the same effect. Even more so, it does not update URL at all now.

```
render () {
        return (
            this.state.redirect 
            ? 
            <Link to={{
                pathname: `/location/${this.state.locationId}`
            }}/>
            :
            <div>
                <LocationPicker 
                    returnLocation={this.setLocation} 
                    locationId={this.state.locationId}
                />
                <h1>Please find bellow all recommendations for {this.state.locationId}</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Any explanation regarding the problem in basic language would also be extremely appreciated. I am just not there yet :(

Cheers and thx alot

Comment: My guess would be that the redirect mid render could be an issue.. I would look at their docs on the `render` prop for `<Routes/>`. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func. You could try either making a higher order component that renders the Route or a Redirect. Sorry... reading again -- Are you not using `<Link/>` to transition routes?

Comment: No, I haven't used Link so far, I thought it didn't really apply here. I'll have a look. If you have an easy example for this, that would be much appreciated! I find the official documentation does not apply to my specific problem as those links are not dynamic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expect to change the route just by changing the `state`. Even with the `<Redirect>` approach that you have used, it only make an infinite redirect loop by setting `this.state.redirect` true. Because `Route` use same LocationDisplay instance with each redirect and `this.state.redirect` will be always true. However, react-router automatically directs this redirect loop and renders a blank.

The correct way to change routes in react-router is use `push` method in [`history`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) object. You can simply call `push` method with your new path name as follows.

```
setLocation(value) {
  this.props.history.push(`/location/${value}`);
}
```

Also, I don't understand why you keep `locationId` in your `state`. It's already in your `props` at `this.props.match.params.locationId`. So there is no point of keep same data in two places because having a single source of truth is ideal. Otherwise, you always have to write additional code lines to keep `locationId` in `state` and `props` sync. So I suggest you to, change your approach to something like this.

```
export default class LocationDisplay extends Component {
  constructor () {
      super();
  }

  setLocation(value) {
    this.props.history.push(`/location/${value}`);
  }

  render () {
    const locationId = this.props.match.params.locationId
    return (
      <div>
        <LocationPicker 
          returnLocation={this.setLocation} 
          locationId={locationId}
        />
        <h1>Please find below all recommendations for {locationId}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

*(This code is just to get an idea. I didn't test this code as I don't have other parts. If you can provide [codepen](http://codepen.io/) or [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with your current implementation I can update it to work.)*

Comment: Tharaka, I REALLY appreciate your feedback! I tried push at some point and remember it to not working then, but I might have used it wrong. I will try to implement your suggestions asap and get back to you then! Regardless, thanks alot for your time.
Quick question though, aren't state and router connected through the <Redirect> part in my code?

Comment: Worked! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you have a valid point with `<Redirect>` even though it's not a common pattern for this kind of use cases. I think it doesn't work because setting `this.state.redirect` true make an infinite redirect loop which react-router automatically detect and render a blank.

Answer (score 1):

For those experiencing this problem with Redux, wrap your `connect` within `withRouter`, as shown here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/blocked-updates.md