# Best practice for dynamic routing (react router v4) needed?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With React Router V4 being out only for a little while and there being no clear documentation on dynamic routing [akin to `transtionsTo(...)` in V3] I feel like a simple answer to this question could benefit many. So here we go.

Lets assume the following theoretical scenario: one has a component **Container**, which includes two other components (**Selection** and **Display**). Now in terms of functionality:
**Container** holds a state, which can be changed by **Selection**, **Display** shows data based on said state.

Now how would one go about changing the URL as well as the state triggered by a change in state via react router?

For a more concrete example please see ([React Router V4 - Page does not rerender on changed Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555754/react-router-v4-page-does-not-rerender-on-changed-route)). However, I felt the need to generalize and shorten the question to get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy to [Tharaka Wijebandara] the solution to this problem is:
Have the **Container** component provide the **Selection** component with a callback function that has to do at least the following on **Container**:

props.history.push(`Selection coming from Selection`);

Please find below an example of the **Container** (called Geoselector) component, passing the setLocation callback down to the **Selection** (called Geosuggest) component.

```
class Geoselector extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.setLocation = this.setLocation.bind(this);
        //Sets location in case of a reload instead of entering via landing
        if (!Session.get('selectedLocation')) {
            let myRe = new RegExp('/location/(.*)');
            let locationFromPath = myRe.exec(this.props.location.pathname)[1];
            Session.set('selectedLocation',locationFromPath);
        }
    }

    setLocation(value) {
        const newLocation = value.label;
        if (Session.get('selectedLocation') != newLocation) {
            Session.set('selectedLocation',newLocation);
            Session.set('locationLngLat',value.location);
            this.props.history.push(`/location/${newLocation}`)
        };
    }


    render () {
        return (
            <Geosuggest 
                onSuggestSelect={this.setLocation} 
                types={['(cities)']}
                placeholder="Please select a location ..."
            />
        )
    }
}
```