# JavaScript .includes() only works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `.includes` to check if likes array in db already includes this user's id which works fine however it only works after refreshing the page or navigating to a different page and then returning.
I have looked at various similar questions but I can't seem to find an answer/solution.
Why isn't it working without refreshing the page?

NOTE: When I check if the user id is equal to the author id of the post OR if the authenticated user has already liked it `post.author && post.author.id === _id || post.likes && post.likes.includes(_id)` the first statement works fine without refreshing the page. There just seems to be an issue with the second one.

Post.js

```js
    const Post = (props) => {
      const [post, setPost] = useState({});
      const [error, setError] = useState(false);
      const id = props.match.params.id;
    
    
      const loadSinglePost = (id) => {
        read(id).then((data) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log(data.error);
            setError(data.error);
          } else {
            setPost(data);
            console.log(data);
          }
        });
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        loadSinglePost(id);
      }, [props]);
    
    const likePost = (id) => {
        const {
          user: { _id },
          token,
        } = isAuthenticated();
        fetch(`${API}/like/${_id}/${id}`, {
          method: "PUT",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: id,
          }),
        })
          .then((result) => {
            const {user: {_id}} = isAuthenticated()
            let updatedPost = { ...post };
{/* condition only works after page refresh. Before page refresh, likes 
are continuously being pushed to array even when the condition has been met. */}
          if (post.likes && post.likes.includes(_id)){
           return null
          } else {
            updatedPost.likes.push(id);
            setPost(updatedPost);
          }})
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      };
    
     const {user: {_id}} = isAuthenticated()
      return (
         <div>
{/* condition only works after page refresh. Before page refresh, button is  always displayed even when the condition has been met. */}
           {post.likes && post.likes.includes(_id) ? "" :
             <button>Like </button>}
         </div>)
        }
```

controllers/posts.js

```js
   exports.like = (req, res) => {
         
   Post.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
   $push: {likes: req.profile._id}
   }, {new: true}).exec((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
    return res.status(422).json({error: err})
     } else {
      return res.json(result)
       }
      })
     }
```

Comment: how is `pages.likes` being updated (without a page refresh)?

Comment: So what do `_id` and `post.likes` look like when they aren't working? Seems like a simple debugging operation to inspect them to figure out why `includes()` isn't doing what you expect

Comment: you're using  let updatedPost = { ...post }; where do you define post? this code above is a component?

Comment: can somebody explain how this can even work    const {user: {_id}} = isAuthenticated()
      return ( )

Comment: are you using `react router`  ?

Comment: @wyfy Yes I am.

Comment: I think I experienced your problem before when using `react router`. When you navigate around with `react router`, your component does not re-render, so `useEffect` is not called. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555754/react-router-v4-page-does-not-rerender-on-changed-route/46368667